# How to register kryo classes in the spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

The `SparkConf` has the method  `registerKryoClasses`:

```
def registerKryoClasses(classes: Array[Class[_]]): SparkConf = { .. }
```

However it is not available/exposed in the `RuntimeConfiguration` facade provided by the `SparkSession.conf()` attribute

```
@transient lazy val conf: RuntimeConfig = new RuntimeConfig(sessionState.conf)
```

Here is more about the `RuntimeConfiguration`:

```
/**
 * Runtime configuration interface for Spark. To access this, use `SparkSession.conf`.
 *
 * Options set here are automatically propagated to the Hadoop configuration during I/O.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
@InterfaceStability.Stable
class RuntimeConfig private[sql](sqlConf: SQLConf = new SQLConf) {
```

There is a clear workaround for this when creating our own `SparkSession`: we can invoke the `set(key,value)` on the `SparkConf` that is provided to the

```
val mysparkConf = SparkConf.set(someKey,someVal)
mysparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Array[InternalRow]]))
SparkSession.builder.conf(mySparkConf)
```

And then one that is *not* so clear..

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[scala.reflect.ClassTag$$anon$1]))
```

But when running the `Spark shell` the `sparkSession`/`sparkContext` are already created.   So then how can the non-runtime settings be put into effect?

The particular need here is :

```
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]))
```

When attempting to set that on the `SqlConf` available to the `spark` session object We get this exception:

```
scala>   spark.conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Row]))
```

> error: value registerKryoClasses is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig
>                spark.conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Row]))

So then how can the kryo serializers be registered in the `spark-shell` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is *not* an exact answer to [my own] question - but it seems to serve as a workaround for the present specific predicament:

```
implicit val generalRowEncoder: Encoder[Row] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[Row]
```

Having this *implicit* in scope seems to register the classes with *kryo* directly on the *SparkConf*.